# Fibonacci Series java

Tags: java

I have generated a program that calculates the fibonacci series with a limit given by the user by keyboard, but I have a problem, since I have asked that the series start at 1, and not at zero as I had done. How can I do that? my fibonacci series shows me from 1 and not from 0?

```
     int maxNumber = 0; 
     int previousNumber = 0;
     int nextNumber = 1;

        System.out.println("How many numbers you want in Fibonacci:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        maxNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Fibonacci Series of "+maxNumber+" numbers:");

        for (int i = 1; i <= maxNumber; ++i)
        {
            System.out.print(previousNumber+" ");


            int sum = previousNumber + nextNumber;
            previousNumber = nextNumber;
            nextNumber = sum;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `int previousNumber = 1;` and it will start from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a simple change and print the number after calculation.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= maxNumber; ++i)
        {
           // System.out.print(previousNumber+" ");


            int sum = previousNumber + nextNumber;
            previousNumber = nextNumber;
            nextNumber = sum;

            System.out.print(previousNumber+" ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

source: [Programmers Interview](http://programmersinterview.blogspot.com/2015/10/java-program-for-fibanacci-series.html)

```
/*Java Program to find the FibonacciSeries */
public class FibonacciSeries {
   public static void main(String a[]){   
         int limit = 15; /* give limit here */
         int[] feb = new int[limit];
         feb[0] = 0;
         feb[1] = 1;
   /* store all elements in array feb[] */
         for(int i=2; i < limit; i++){
             feb[i] = feb[i-1] + feb[i-2];
         }
    /* print all array elements */
         for(int i=0; i< limit; i++){
                 System.out.print(feb[i] + " ");
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number  of terms: ");
        int count=scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        
        int firstTerm=1;
        int secondTerm=2;
        int nextTerm;
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.print("Fibonacci Series: ");
        System.out.print(firstTerm+","+secondTerm);
        
        for(int i=3; i<=count; i++) {
            nextTerm=firstTerm+secondTerm;
            System.out.print(","+nextTerm);
            firstTerm=secondTerm;
            secondTerm=nextTerm;
        }
}
```